# Привязка текста к кнопке

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть динамическая кнопка и есть текст который на ней.
Как прикрепить текст к кнопке , чтобы он следовал за ней.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <h2>Enter</h2>
```

**Css**

```
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  top: 238px;
  left: 538px;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

#### Описание

Ответ - [`position: relative;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).
Relative то и значит - "относительно", то есть позиция дочернего элемента подсчитывается относительно родителя. Куда вы бы не переместили элемент, дочерние элементы будут следить за ним.

Comment: Каким образом это реализовать

Comment: @vitaliy125 поэтому оставил ссылку. По ссылке почти сразу увидите пример.